# java.lang.NullPointerException while calling a method from another class

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm new to Java and Android development. I'm developing an app for children, in the Java section contain some classes. One of the classes is for swapping the pages named `ColorCustomSwipeAdapter`, and there is another class for converting text to speech named `ReadName` that contain a method named `speakOut`, the problem starts when I try to call the method `speakOut` through the `ColorCustomSwipeAdapter` class. It throws `NPE` and the app crashes.

Here is the code:

**ColorCustomSwipeAdapter.java**

```
package com.example.ibrahim.toddlerssmartbook;

import android.content.Context;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.Locale;

 /**
    * Created by Ibrahim on 3/19/2016.
 */
public class ColorCustomSwipeAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

ReadName sayName=new ReadName() ;
private int[] image_resource = {R.drawable.red,R.drawable.green,R.drawable.blue,R.drawable.pink,R.drawable.gray ,R.drawable.yellow,R.drawable.brown,
           R.drawable.black,R.drawable.purple,R.drawable.orange,R.drawable.white};
private String[] color_name=   {"Red","Green","Blue","Pink","Gray","Yellow","Brown","Black","Purple","Orange","White"};
 private Context ctx;
  private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
public ColorCustomSwipeAdapter(MainActivity ctx){this.ctx=ctx;}
@Override

public int getCount() {
    return image_resources.length;
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return (view==(LinearLayout)object);
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {

    layoutInflater= (LayoutInflater) ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
      View    item_view=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.swipe_layout,container,false);
    ImageView imageView=(ImageView)item_view.findViewById(R.id.image_view);
    TextView textView=(TextView)item_view.findViewById(R.id.name);
    imageView.setImageResource(image_resources[position]);
    textView.setText(color_name[position]);

    sayName.speakOut(color_name[position]);//The ERROR IS HERE

    container.addView(item_view);
    return item_view;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        container.removeView((LinearLayout)object);
    }
}
```

**Readname.java**

```
package com.example.ibrahim.toddlerssmartbook;

import android.content.Context;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Locale;

/**
   * Created by Ibrahim on 4/7/2016.
*/
public class ReadName extends AppCompatActivity {
private int result;

public ReadName() {
   result=0;
}

 TextToSpeech  ttsObject=new TextToSpeech(this,new              TextToSpeech.OnInitListener(){
   @Override
 public void onInit(int status){
 if(status==TextToSpeech.SUCCESS){
result = ttsObject.setLanguage(Locale.US);
}else{
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Feature not supported in your    device.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }}
  });
  public void speakOut(String name){

 if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED || result ==    TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA) {
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Feature not supported in your    device.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   } else {
      ttsObject.speak(name, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
   }
  }
   @Override
   public void onDestroy() {

    if (ttsObject != null) {
        ttsObject.stop();
        ttsObject.shutdown();
    }
    super.onDestroy();
 }
}
```

Comment: Can you include the stack trace that shows the `NullPointerException`?

Comment: The error is probably coming earlier in the method because it doesn't look like you ever instantiate `ctx`

Comment: It is a really bad practice to initialize global variables when declaring it, use instead the constructor or some method

Comment: @JamesMcCracken Here is the stack trace: 04-10 14:35:12.139 29581-29581/com.example.ibrahim.toddlerssamertbook E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-10 14:35:12.139 29581-29581/com.example.ibrahim.toddlerssamertbook E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NullPointerException